# How to multi-line echo json from a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, echo

When I run `docker build .` when my docker file is

```
FROM node:8
RUN echo -e '{
    "a" : "b"
}'
```

I get

> Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 3: unknown instruction: "A":

Is there a way to do this multiline? I have 10 variable json file I want to enter manually like this, to override some variables.

I have also tried `echo -e` and `printf`

Comment: Try backslashes at the end of each line.

Comment: @dfundako solved, feel free to leave as answer and I can mark as solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\n\` this will keep the file in structure as well, as sometime new line is required in some config file while with `\` this it will print in a single line.

```
FROM node:8
RUN echo '{ \n\
    "a" : "b", \n\
    "c" : "d", \n\
    "e" : "f" \n\
}'
```

[image]